# Expected spy to have been called error because of if statement

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing a angular 11 unit test case for code inside if block. when I comment the if block, all the tests gets passed, but with if block it is bot going inside my if block.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEXAQ.png)

**splash-screen.service.ts**

```
init() {
    // Get the splash screen element
    this.splashScreenEl = this.document.body.querySelector('#splash-screen');
      
      this.router.events.pipe(filter((event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)), take(1)).subscribe(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // If the splash screen element exists...
          // Hide it on the first NavigationEnd event
          if (this.splashScreenEl) {
            this.hide();
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

**splash-screen.service.ts**

```
it('should call hide method with end navigation event', fakeAsync(() => {
    const methodSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(service, 'hide');
    eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, 'http://localhost:4200/', 'http://localhost:4200/'));
    tick();
    const splashScreenEl = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(true);
    service.splashScreenEl = splashScreenEl;
    expect(service.splashScreenEl).toBeTruthy();
    expect(methodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

how I can make this test case to pass.

PS: I am very much new to jasmine test case.

Comment: eventSubject is used to mock the routing event. based on the routing event I am calling this.hide method. this method will stop the loader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out why this is returning false:

```
this.document.body.querySelector('#splash-screen');
```

If you want to explicitly set `splashScreenEl` to true, you can do so by the following:

```
it('should call hide method with end navigation event', fakeAsync(() => {
    const methodSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(service, 'hide');
    eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, 'http://localhost:4200/', 'http://localhost:4200/'));
    // add a 0 on tick to make 0ms pass by (could be optional)
    tick(0);
    // add this line, make it explicitly true
    service.splashScreenEl = true;
    expect(service.splashScreenEl).toBeTruthy();
    expect(methodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Comment: I had tried making `service.splashScreenEl = true;` explicitly, but still test case is failing.

Comment: Not sure why then, sorry.